# Simple dynamic Google Maps issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a dynamic map using Google's API. I'm trying to get the map to dynamically apply the info boxes for each marker.. and I can't figure it out:

http://www.zephyrusdevelopment.com/clients/electrotrack/map2.html

Comment: While it's good to post a link to an example, it's generally better to *also* post snippets from the relevant code, so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that next time. I figured it out, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're falling into the classic loop-plus-closure error, which in simplified form looks like this:

```
while(i<=(a_l-1)) {
    // snip
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        // snip
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    // snip
}
```

The problem is that, due to the way closures work in Javascript, the handler function will keep a persistent reference to the `marker` variable, even after it is assigned to a new object. End result: all your handlers reference the last object assigned to `marker`.

There are several ways to fix this; I usually use a separate function to assign the click handler, which captures the correct `marker` object in the handler scope:

```
function addClickHandler(marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}

while(i<=(a_l-1)) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        // snip
    });
    addClickHandler(marker);
}
```

Comment: Yes, what I did, if you look, was put the whole handler outside of the loop. Thanks for your help though! :)

Comment: If this was the right answer, you can mark it correct by clicking the checkmark next to it - thanks!